# Adding list of users to list of computers. -logonworkstations to , i need a script for list of users,computeras in csv and each user to map with comp

Tags: powershell

I have a list of users and computers in csv

csv format

```
User  computer
xyx    comp1
zzz     comp2
axsc    comp3
```

```
$ADusername = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\xyx\Desktop\user.csv"
>> $complist = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\computer.csv" | ForEach-Object {$_.NetBIOSName}
>> $comparray = $complist -join ","
>> Set-ADUser -id $_.UserList -LogonWorkstations $comparray
```

> Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
> At line:4 char:16
> + Set-ADUser -id $_.UserList -LogonWorkstations $comparray
> +                ~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException

Comment: Seems like there are pieces of your code missing. You're using `-id $_.UserList` but there is no loop to reference `$_.UserList` please double check your code in question

Comment: Your example suggests you have one CSV file with both uaser and computer names in it, but your code apparently loads two different files as input. Please open both csv files in notepad and copy the first 3 or 4 lines from them as-is. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71256132/edit) your question and paste that in there so we can see how a username matches the designated computer names